# xPages View - Display categegorized View as Bootstrap Grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I what to display a categorized view as Bootstrap Grid (not as Table). For one document there should be multiple rows to display the columns of the view and on large devices there should be just one row. The categories should be collapsible/expandable.

I used nested repeat controls. In the outer repeat control I display the categories of the view, in the inner repeat control I display a single categorized view, with the category as filter. I can format the 'columns' as Bootstrap grid and archive the look I want. But there are some disadvantages:

- Maximum Number of Rows

  There seams to be no way to limit the number of total rows display in one pager page this way. So that I always have 50 lines displayed no matter if a category is expanded or not.
- One or no Pager

  If there is one or no pager the categories list or the list of documents within one category can be very long.
- Two Pagers

  If there is a pager for the outer and the inner view. This will be very unfamiliar IBM Notes users. Very short lists of document in a category will have a pager too.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I would use a custom rest control that delivers exactly the Json you need for the GUI. You are not limited by row limits there and you can do some aggressive caching for categories

Comment: @stwissel Any example for that on the web? Do I have to do the 'table' handling completely myself in Client JavaScript myself?

Comment: If you're using a grid, then typically they just want the data in json format and you do NOT need to send any html markup

Comment: @DavidLeedy I'm talking about the Bootstrap Grid System (Layout), not any data grid project. By the way there seam to be no data grid project, that is using bootstrap grid layout, they all use tables.

Comment: OK.  I misunderstood then.  Yeah bootstrap does not come with a data grid project itself but I think many out there do support bootstrap styling.  I know DataTables does at least.  https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap

Comment: I think it's difficult to answer this would maybe some mockup screens of what exactly you're trying to do.  I've not a lot with nested repeat controls but I've not tried the things your talking about.  I would suggest though that you do NOT try to make it look like the notes client. Web UI's are different and more flexable.  Whenever I hear "Catagorized view" I would suggest that a more common Web UI is to have the categories in drop downs filtering the list of results. So you might want to just consider the ui itself.